# Reference Error - SHA-1 for node_modules\@react-native\metro-config\node_modules\@react-native\js-polyfills\console.js is not computed

Tags: android, react-native, sha1, mobile-development, metro-bundler

Trying to run my app on react native android uses metro/yarn. Recieved the error in the title. Full error message below.
`ReferenceError: SHA-1 for file C:\Users\usr\app\node_modules\@react-native\metro-config\node_modules\@react-native\js-polyfills\console.js (C:\Users\usr\app\node_modules\@react-native\metro-config\node_modules\@react-native\js-polyfills\console.js) is not computed. Potential causes: 1) You have symlinks in your project - watchman does not follow symlinks. 2) Check` blockList `in your metro.config.js and make sure it isn't excluding the file path. at DependencyGraph.getSha1 (C:\Users\usr\app\realapp\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:215:13) at Transformer._getSha1 (C:\Users\usr\lace\realapp\node_modules\metro\src\Bundler.js:26:26) at Transformer.transformFile (C:\Users\usr\lace\realapp\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Transformer.js:107:19) at Bundler.transformFile (C:\Users\usr\app\realapp\node_modules\metro\src\Bundler.js:60:30) at async Object.transform (C:\Users\usr\app\realapp\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:150:12) at async Graph._processModule (C:\Users\usr\app\lace\realapp\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Graph.js:257:20) at async Graph._traverseDependenciesForSingleFile (C:\Users\usr\app\realapp\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Graph.js:249:5) at async Promise.all (index 1) at async Graph.initialTraverseDependencies (C:\Users\usr\app\realapp\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Graph.js:233:5) at async DeltaCalculator._getChangedDependencies (C:\Users\usr\app\realapp\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\DeltaCalculator.js:229:25)`

Expected the app to run.

Answer (score 0):

Clear expo cache

```
expo start -c
```

Reinstall Node Modules

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

Restart Watchman

```
watchman watch-del-all
watchman shutdown-server
```

and you should be good to go